# Rome Metro Line C (Pigneto station) - is it open?

Tags: trains, public-transport, rome

I am planning a trip to Rome for early October 2019. I found some good deals on accommodation near Pigneto metro station. However, I find conflicting information about that station and line C in general. Is it open? If so how much of it is, and are there any restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pigneto station is fully open and operational, and so is line C from San Giovanni to Monte Compatri/Pantano (and not only on Wikipedia, but also in real life).

I know that personal experience and personally often using that station is not a formal source, but I wonder what I can do more. Taking some photographs there, perhaps? A confirmation comes from the [official website of Rome transports](http://viaggiacon.atac.roma.it/?service=trovalinea&linea=METROC&percorso=METROCA#), which gives the timetables and other information for line C.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia line C is open, and as of May 2018 it is no longer unconnected from lines A & B since there is now transfer to line A at San Giovanni station.

So you're probably OK.

Comment: After checking wikipedia and digging some more, I found this site that seems to give much detail about the status of that metro line: http://metrocspa.it/en/the-work/